# jQuery:the different behavior of the tablet PC and the dblclick and mousedown events

Tags: jquery, mousedown

I try to make some web pages, in same time suitable for PC browser and tablet (running Android). I started my web pages with this in page header:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

and bellow it is a long code that deal with dblclick and mousedown on table cell, where jQuery open proper dialogs, and until it works fine on PC, when I connected with tablet it recognize **mousedown** events on cell but not **dblclick**; instead to open proper dialog the screen is resizing (getting smaller)! I tried many times but dblclick isn't recognized as PC did (open a dialog).
Do I need to develop separate web site suited for tablet and others for PC, or it's possible to get tablet's right respond with some code changes?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no dblclick event fired on a touch device (including Windows 10 touchscreens, so this is not exclusive to tablet/mobile devices), but if you're using [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), there is a [tap event](https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/) and a [taphold event](https://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/) that you may be able to leverage.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, thank you for your fast response. In meantime I considered **touchstart** where is possible to solve single and double tap, but then press & hold remain unsolved.